# Uncaught Error: Class 'Memcache' not found on XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, memcached

I use XAMPP and I've installed Memcached but the apps who need it still don't work and return :

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Memcache' not found
```

I have installed the following packages : ''php-memcached'' and ''memcached'' and I use a symlink for php (ln -s /usr/bin/php /opt/lampp/bin/).

Here is my phpinfo() output :

```
PHP Version => 7.0.19-1

System => Linux debian-n 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u1 (2017-06-18) x86_64
Build Date => May 11 2017 14:04:47
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-memcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-msgpack.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini

PHP API => 20151012
PHP Extension => 20151012
Zend Extension => 320151012
Zend Extension Build => API320151012,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20151012,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => disabled
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => available, disabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv2, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, convert.iconv.*

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.19-1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

calendar

Calendar support => enabled

Core

PHP Version => 7.0.19-1

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => UTF-8 => UTF-8
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => Off => Off
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
exit_on_timeout => Off => Off
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20151012 => /usr/lib/php/20151012
file_uploads => On => On
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .:/usr/share/php => .:/usr/share/php
input_encoding => no value => no value
internal_encoding => no value => no value
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => On => On
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => -1 => -1
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_encoding => no value => no value
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 8M => 8M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 4096K => 4096K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => GP => GP
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i  => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 
serialize_precision => 17 => 17
short_open_tag => Off => Off
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sql.safe_mode => Off => Off
sys_temp_dir => no value => no value
track_errors => Off => Off
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.assertions => -1 => -1
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

date

date/time support => enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => Europe/Berlin

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => no value => no value

exif

EXIF Support => enabled
EXIF Version => 1.4 $Id: 8bdc0c8f27c2c9dd1f7551f1f9fe3ab57a06a4b1 $
Supported EXIF Version => 0220
Supported filetypes => JPEG,TIFF

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel => UCS-2LE => UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola => UCS-2BE => UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis => no value => no value
exif.encode_unicode => ISO-8859-15 => ISO-8859-15

fileinfo

fileinfo support => enabled
version => 1.0.5
libmagic => 522

filter

Input Validation and Filtering => enabled
Revision => $Id: 28fcca4bfda9c9907588a64d245b49cb398249d8 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
filter.default => unsafe_raw => unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags => no value => no value

ftp

FTP support => enabled
FTPS support => enabled

gettext

GetText Support => enabled

hash

hash support => enabled
Hashing Engines => md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost gost-crypto adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv1a32 fnv164 fnv1a64 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5 

MHASH support => Enabled
MHASH API Version => Emulated Support

iconv

iconv support => enabled
iconv implementation => glibc
iconv library version => 2.24

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
iconv.input_encoding => no value => no value
iconv.internal_encoding => no value => no value
iconv.output_encoding => no value => no value

igbinary

igbinary support => enabled
igbinary version => 2.0.1
igbinary APCU serializer ABI => 0
igbinary session support => yes

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
igbinary.compact_strings => On => On

json

json support => enabled
json version => 1.4.0

libxml

libXML support => active
libXML Compiled Version => 2.9.4
libXML Loaded Version => 20904
libXML streams => enabled

memcache

memcache support => enabled
Version => 3.0.9-dev
Revision => $Revision$

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
memcache.allow_failover => 1 => 1
memcache.chunk_size => 32768 => 32768
memcache.compress_threshold => 20000 => 20000
memcache.default_port => 11211 => 11211
memcache.hash_function => crc32 => crc32
memcache.hash_strategy => consistent => consistent
memcache.lock_timeout => 15 => 15
memcache.max_failover_attempts => 20 => 20
memcache.protocol => ascii => ascii
memcache.redundancy => 1 => 1
memcache.session_redundancy => 2 => 2

memcached

memcached support => enabled
Version => 3.0.1
libmemcached version => 1.0.18
SASL support => yes
Session support => yes
igbinary support => yes
json support => yes
msgpack support => yes

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
memcached.compression_factor => 1.3 => 1.3
memcached.compression_threshold => 2000 => 2000
memcached.compression_type => fastlz => fastlz
memcached.default_binary_protocol => 0 => 0
memcached.default_connect_timeout => 0 => 0
memcached.default_consistent_hash => 0 => 0
memcached.serializer => php => php
memcached.sess_binary_protocol => 1 => 1
memcached.sess_connect_timeout => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_consistent_hash => 1 => 1
memcached.sess_lock_expire => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_lock_max_wait => not set => not set
memcached.sess_lock_retries => 5 => 5
memcached.sess_lock_wait => not set => not set
memcached.sess_lock_wait_max => 2000 => 2000
memcached.sess_lock_wait_min => 1000 => 1000
memcached.sess_locking => 1 => 1
memcached.sess_number_of_replicas => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_persistent => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_prefix => memc.sess. => memc.sess.
memcached.sess_randomize_replica_read => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_remove_failed_servers => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_sasl_password => no value => no value
memcached.sess_sasl_username => no value => no value
memcached.sess_server_failure_limit => 0 => 0
memcached.store_retry_count => 2 => 2

msgpack

MessagePack Support => enabled
Session Support => enabled
extension Version => 2.0.2
header Version => 0.5.4

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
msgpack.error_display => On => On
msgpack.illegal_key_insert => Off => Off
msgpack.php_only => On => On
msgpack.use_str8_serialization => On => On

openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value

pcntl

pcntl support => enabled

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.39 2016-06-14
PCRE JIT Support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.jit => 1 => 1
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers =>  

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled
Phar EXT version => 2.0.2
Phar API version => 1.1.1
SVN revision => $Id: 9d91fd26ae99260111b934cc25174387d4bd7059 $
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Tar-based phar archives => enabled
ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
gzip compression => enabled
bzip2 compression => disabled (install pecl/bz2)
Native OpenSSL support => enabled


Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
phar.cache_list => no value => no value
phar.readonly => On => On
phar.require_hash => On => On

posix

Revision => $Id: b691ca925e7a085e6929579c4eba8fed0732e0ef $

readline

Readline Support => enabled
Readline library => EditLine wrapper

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
cli.pager => no value => no value
cli.prompt => \b \>  => \b \> 

Reflection

Reflection => enabled
Version => $Id: 7d703262f14bc65e05ff76fb3714c945f9bf961a $

session

Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user memcache memcached 
Registered serializer handlers => php_serialize php php_binary igbinary msgpack 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => Off => Off
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_secure => Off => Off
session.entropy_file => /dev/urandom => /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length => 32 => 32
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 0 => 0
session.hash_bits_per_character => 5 => 5
session.hash_function => 0 => 0
session.lazy_write => On => On
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => /var/lib/php/sessions => /var/lib/php/sessions
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => On => On
session.use_only_cookies => On => On
session.use_strict_mode => Off => Off
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0

shmop

shmop support => enabled

sockets

Sockets Support => enabled

SPL

SPL support => enabled
Interfaces => Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

standard

Dynamic Library Support => enabled
Path to sendmail => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
assert.active => 1 => 1
assert.bail => 0 => 0
assert.callback => no value => no value
assert.exception => 0 => 0
assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0
assert.warning => 1 => 1
auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0
default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
from => no value => no value
url_rewriter.tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent => no value => no value

sysvmsg

sysvmsg support => enabled
Revision => $Id: dfb999763f95bfe9609fae60b4e07a492888ec7c $

sysvsem

Version => 7.0.19-1

sysvshm

Version => 7.0.19-1

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support => enabled

Zend OPcache

Opcode Caching => Disabled
Optimization => Disabled
SHM Cache => Enabled
File Cache => Disabled
Startup Failed => Opcode Caching is disabled for CLI

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
opcache.blacklist_filename => no value => no value
opcache.consistency_checks => 0 => 0
opcache.dups_fix => Off => Off
opcache.enable => On => On
opcache.enable_cli => Off => Off
opcache.enable_file_override => Off => Off
opcache.error_log => no value => no value
opcache.fast_shutdown => 0 => 0
opcache.file_cache => no value => no value
opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks => 1 => 1
opcache.file_cache_only => 0 => 0
opcache.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
opcache.force_restart_timeout => 180 => 180
opcache.huge_code_pages => Off => Off
opcache.inherited_hack => On => On
opcache.interned_strings_buffer => 4 => 4
opcache.lockfile_path => /tmp => /tmp
opcache.log_verbosity_level => 1 => 1
opcache.max_accelerated_files => 2000 => 2000
opcache.max_file_size => 0 => 0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage => 5 => 5
opcache.memory_consumption => 64 => 64
opcache.optimization_level => 0x7FFFBFFF => 0x7FFFBFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model => no value => no value
opcache.protect_memory => 0 => 0
opcache.restrict_api => no value => no value
opcache.revalidate_freq => 2 => 2
opcache.revalidate_path => Off => Off
opcache.save_comments => 1 => 1
opcache.use_cwd => On => On
opcache.validate_permission => Off => Off
opcache.validate_root => Off => Off
opcache.validate_timestamps => On => On

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.8
Linked Version => 1.2.8

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Additional Modules

Module Name

Environment

Variable => Value
LS_COLORS => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
XDG_MENU_PREFIX => gnome-
LANG => fr_FR.UTF-8
GDM_LANG => fr_FR.UTF-8
DISPLAY => :0
OLDPWD => /home
COLORTERM => truecolor
USERNAME => nino
XDG_VTNR => 2
SSH_AUTH_SOCK => /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
XDG_SESSION_ID => 2
USER => nino
DESKTOP_SESSION => default
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME => qgnomeplatform
PWD => /etc/php/7.0/cli
HOME => /home/nino
JOURNAL_STREAM => 8:21052
SSH_AGENT_PID => 1108
QT_ACCESSIBILITY => 1
XDG_SESSION_TYPE => x11
XDG_DATA_DIRS => /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP => default
GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT => stderr
GTK_MODULES => gail:atk-bridge
WINDOWPATH => 2
TERM => xterm-256color
SHELL => /bin/bash
VTE_VERSION => 4601
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP => GNOME
GPG_AGENT_INFO => /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON => 1
SHLVL => 1
XDG_SEAT => seat0
WINDOWID => 27262982
GDMSESSION => default
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID => this-is-deprecated
LOGNAME => nino
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS => unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR => /run/user/1000
XAUTHORITY => /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
PATH => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS => JS ERROR;JS LOG
SESSION_MANAGER => local/debian-n:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1062,unix/debian-n:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1062
_ => /opt/lampp/bin/php

PHP Variables

Variable => Value
$_SERVER['LS_COLORS'] => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
$_SERVER['XDG_MENU_PREFIX'] => gnome-
$_SERVER['LANG'] => fr_FR.UTF-8
$_SERVER['GDM_LANG'] => fr_FR.UTF-8
$_SERVER['DISPLAY'] => :0
$_SERVER['OLDPWD'] => /home
$_SERVER['COLORTERM'] => truecolor
$_SERVER['USERNAME'] => nino
$_SERVER['XDG_VTNR'] => 2
$_SERVER['SSH_AUTH_SOCK'] => /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
$_SERVER['XDG_SESSION_ID'] => 2
$_SERVER['USER'] => nino
$_SERVER['DESKTOP_SESSION'] => default
$_SERVER['QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME'] => qgnomeplatform
$_SERVER['PWD'] => /etc/php/7.0/cli
$_SERVER['HOME'] => /home/nino
$_SERVER['JOURNAL_STREAM'] => 8:21052
$_SERVER['SSH_AGENT_PID'] => 1108
$_SERVER['QT_ACCESSIBILITY'] => 1
$_SERVER['XDG_SESSION_TYPE'] => x11
$_SERVER['XDG_DATA_DIRS'] => /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
$_SERVER['XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP'] => default
$_SERVER['GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT'] => stderr
$_SERVER['GTK_MODULES'] => gail:atk-bridge
$_SERVER['WINDOWPATH'] => 2
$_SERVER['TERM'] => xterm-256color
$_SERVER['SHELL'] => /bin/bash
$_SERVER['VTE_VERSION'] => 4601
$_SERVER['XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP'] => GNOME
$_SERVER['GPG_AGENT_INFO'] => /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
$_SERVER['QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON'] => 1
$_SERVER['SHLVL'] => 1
$_SERVER['XDG_SEAT'] => seat0
$_SERVER['WINDOWID'] => 27262982
$_SERVER['GDMSESSION'] => default
$_SERVER['GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID'] => this-is-deprecated
$_SERVER['LOGNAME'] => nino
$_SERVER['DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'] => unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
$_SERVER['XDG_RUNTIME_DIR'] => /run/user/1000
$_SERVER['XAUTHORITY'] => /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
$_SERVER['PATH'] => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
$_SERVER['GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS'] => JS ERROR;JS LOG
$_SERVER['SESSION_MANAGER'] => local/debian-n:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1062,unix/debian-n:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1062
$_SERVER['_'] => /opt/lampp/bin/php
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] => 
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] => 
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] => 
$_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'] => 
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] => 
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] => 1498409509.0795
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] => 1498409509
$_SERVER['argv'] => Array
(
)

$_SERVER['argc'] => 0
```

How could I make memcached to work ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to have just PHP Memcache module installed. You should have Memcached server module counterpart as well. So you need to install and configure it first. For example, install:

```
apt-get install memcached php5-memcache
```

then check if installed:

```
netstat -tap | grep memcached
```

If it is, you need to configure it by adding to memchached.conf following line:

```
-l 127.0.0.1
```

then restart the memcached and you good to go!

```
/etc/init.d/memcached restart
```

Comment: Its `memcached php-memcached` for my distro.    
  
  
netstat return `tcp        0      0 localhost:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3425/memcached` and I've already have `-l 127.0.0.1` in memcached.conf

Comment: Check what is this code will return: 
`<?php

$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

$version = $memcache->getVersion();
echo "Server's version: ".$version."<br/>\n";`

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Memcache' not found in file.php:1 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in file.php on line 1`

Comment: Well, I think the problem is in extension/module, because in my case with given example it's working ok. Sorry to hear it doesn't work for you. Maybe try different versions?